# Como mostrar el indice 0 de un array en php?

Tags: php, php7

Muy buenas noches a todos, yo tengo una duda, con este código, el cual no puedo mostrar el indice 0 que contiene el int 2, como podrán ver lo mando por la url el numero y luego lo busco en el array, los indices que logro mostrar son del 1 al 7, los cuales esta bien, pero el indice 0 por que no me lo muestra? si mando 2 por la url me dice que no existe.

```
     <?php  
        $numeros = array(9,4,6,2,7,3,5,8);

        sort($numeros);                 //ordeno los elementos

        echo count($numeros);           //muestro los elementos

        //Busqueda en array


        if (isset($_GET['numero'])) {

            $busqueda = $_GET['numero'];

            echo'<h3>'."Buscar en array el numero ".$busqueda.'</h3>';

            $search=array_search($busqueda,$numeros);

            if (!empty($search)) {

                echo "<h4>El numero buscado existe en el array, en el indice: 

        $search</h4>";

               }else if(empty($search)) {

                echo"No existe el numero buscado";

            }

        }
array (size=8)
  0 => int 2
  1 => int 3
  2 => int 4
  3 => int 5
  4 => int 6
  5 => int 7
  6 => int 8
  7 => int 9
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considero que el código se puede simplificar bastante en los siguientes puntos:

1. Se puede valorar el estado del `$_GET` con un ternario, usando simplemente `empty`
2. Dado que `array_search` devuelve `FALSE` si no encuentra nada, una evaluación con `in_array` es redundante.
3. No veo por qué haya que igualar `$busqueda = $numero`  ¿?
4. La lógica tiene agujeros: a. Se declaran variables sin siquiera saber si se van a usar; b. El código es mudo si no se postea nada

Propondría algo así:

```
$numero = ( !empty($_GET['numero']) ) ? $_GET['numero'] : NULL;
if ($numero) {
    $numeros = array(9,4,6,2,7,3,5,8);
    sort($numeros);
    $msg="<h3>Buscar en array el numero $numero</h3>";
    $hasIndex = array_search($numero,$numeros) ;
    #Hacemos una comparación estricta, sino consideraría el índice 0 como FALSE
    $msg.= ( $hasIndex!==FALSE ) ? "El número $numero existe en la posición: {$hasIndex}" :  "No existe el número $numero en el array"; 
} else {
    $msg="No se posteó ningún número, revise los datos";
}
echo $msg;
```

Comment: @BernalHD considero esta debería ser la respuesta aceptada

Answer (score 2):

- Usaría primero la función [in_array()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.in-array.php) para verificar que el número pasado en la variable `$numeros` existe.
- Posterior hago uso como ya lo tienes en tu código de la función [array_search](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-search.php) para encontrar la posición dentro del vector de dicho elemento
- Además muevo al `if()` principal la revisión que la variable exista y que no este vacía
- Hago uso de [sort](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.sort.php) para ordenar los valores del vector
- Sustituí por fines de *pruebas* tu variable `$_GET` por una variable llamada `$numero`

**Código de ejemplo**

```
        $numeros = array(9,4,6,2,7,3,5,8);

        sort($numeros);

        $numero = 121;

        if (isset($numero) && !empty($numero)) {

            $busqueda = $numero;

            echo'<h3>'."Buscar en array el numero ".$busqueda.'</h3>';

                if(in_array($busqueda, $numeros)){
                    $encuentra = array_search($busqueda,$numeros);
                    echo "El número existe en la posición: {$encuentra}";
                }else {

                echo"No existe el numero buscado";
                }

        }
```

**Salida**

```
Buscar en array el numero 2
El número existe en la posición: 0
```

Comment: Traté de mejorar el formato de la respuesta y un error con las llaves de paso

Answer (score 1):

Debes cambiar `empty($search)` ya que cuando `$search` es 0  en `empty` lo toma como vacio. Personalmente preguntara si dicha variable es un numero:  `is_numeric($search)`

Answer (score 1):

Muchisimas gracias por las respuestas, después de estar mirando y analizando, use este código. así como me dijo un compañero no le pongo condición al else. Espero que a alguien mas le sirva.

```
$numero = $_GET['numero'];
if (isset($numero) && !empty($numero)) {
    $busqueda = $numero;
    echo'<h3>'."Buscar en array el numero ".$busqueda.'</h3>';
    if(in_array($busqueda, $numeros)){
        $search=array_search($busqueda,$numeros);
        echo "El número existe en la posición: {$search}";
    }
    else{
        echo"No existe el numero buscado";
    }
}
```